# Language and Approach to a Drag-and-Drop Drawing Area for a new CAD GUI?

Tags: c#, user-interface, drawing, cad

I'm trying to make a new CAD program from scratch.  The GUI is mostly easy to make in C#; it's just dragging-and-dropping things like command buttons and writing their associated code.

However I want the user of my CAD to be able to drag-and-drop icons from a toolbar onto a drawing pane.  I also want them to be able to resize those icons, draw connections between them, etc.  And I don't know how to do this part.

After doing a good bit of research, I'm still lost on what approach I should take for it.  It's basically a 2D flowsheet, so do I need hardware acceleration?  Do I make C# bitmaps and just print those after modifications on mouse events?  Etc.

What should I study to learn how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to work with WPF. You might find these articles useful

- [A Beginners Guide to
  WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22980/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-1-of-n)
- [A Guided Tour of WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18232/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-1-XAML)
- [Drag and Drop](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html)
- [Drag and Drop in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43614/Drag-and-Drop-in-WPF)
- [WPF Drag and Drop Smorgasbord](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37161/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-Smorgasbord)
- [Drag And Drop in WPF Explained](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2007/07/12/drag-drop-in-wpf-explained-end-to-end.aspx) (an end-to-end explanation)
- [WPF Diagram Designer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)

These were the ones that help me while I was going to do something similar. Hope they will be useful to you.